# Support for annual events

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to say that an event happens on the same day every year?  For example adding a birthday to a calendar.  I've looked through [the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) but I can't see that it is supported, or if it his, how do to it.

Answer (score -1):

Well... sadly, you need to use viewRender event and assign current year to the date.
This is a functionality that has been awaited for an long time ;'-(
If you discovery another way, please, tell me!